# File cannot be downloaded with Microsoft Teams messaging extension

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a web service that deploys with Microsoft Teams messaging extensions.

I wrote the code to get the data from the server and download the file, but it works in the web browser version of Teams, but not in the desktop client version.
It seems that "" does not work for the desktop client version. Is there any workaround?

```
  axios.post('/download', {
      param: '',
    },
    {
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = url
      link.setAttribute('download', 'download.csv')
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
      document.body.removeChild(link)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: From where you are invoking messaging extension, can you tell the context?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this and I faced no issue. One thing that I have noticed is Teams doesn't show anything like downloading but when I checked Downloads folder, it was getting downloaded. I modified your code a little bit have a look.

```
response.blob().then(img => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(img);
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'download.png');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
```